# Adding a 3rd button and have date picker for time

Tags: iphone

NEW CODE

```
DatePickerViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol DatePickerViewControllerDelegate;

@interface DatePickerViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    id<DatePickerViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (assign) id<DatePickerViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

NSInteger buttonPressed;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end

@protocol DatePickerViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)datePickerViewController:(DatePickerViewController *)controller didChooseDate:(NSString *)chosenDate;


@end


DatePickerViewController.m

#import "DatePickerViewController.h"

@implementation DatePickerViewController

@synthesize datePicker, delegate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = @"Date Picker";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"Date Picker. viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    double days = 2.0f;
    datePicker.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60.0f * 60.0f * 24.0f * days];

}


//-(void)datePickerViewController:(DatePickerViewController *)controller didChooseDate:(NSString *)chosenDate;

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datePickerViewController:didChooseDate:)]) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

        NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];

        [self.delegate datePickerViewController:self didChooseDate:dateString];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }




}

- (void)dealloc {
    [datePicker release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

DatePickerViewController2.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol DatePickerViewController2Delegate;

@interface DatePickerViewController2 : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker2;
    id<DatePickerViewController2Delegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker2;
@property (assign) id<DatePickerViewController2Delegate> delegate;

NSInteger buttonPressed2;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed2:(id)sender;
@end

@protocol DatePickerViewController2Delegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void)datePickerViewController2:(DatePickerViewController2 *)controller didChooseDate:(NSString *)chosenDate;


@end

DatePickerViewController2.m

#import "DatePickerViewController2.h"

@implementation DatePickerViewController2

@synthesize datePicker2, delegate;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = @"Date Picker2";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"Date Picker2. viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    double days = 2.0f;
    datePicker2.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60.0f * 60.0f * 24.0f * days];

}


//-(void)datePickerViewController:(DatePickerViewController *)controller didChooseDate:(NSString *)chosenDate;

- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed2:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(datePickerViewController2:didChooseDate:)]) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

        NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[datePicker2 date]];

        [self.delegate datePickerViewController2:self didChooseDate:dateString];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }




}

- (void)dealloc {
    [datePicker2 release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

DatePickerModalExampleAppDelegate.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DatePickerModalExampleViewController;

@interface DatePickerModalExampleAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    DatePickerModalExampleViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet DatePickerModalExampleViewController *viewController;

@end
DatePickerModalExampleAppDelegate.m
#import "DatePickerModalExampleAppDelegate.h"
#import "DatePickerModalExampleViewController.h"

@implementation DatePickerModalExampleAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 

    // Override point for customization after app launch 
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end

DatePickerModalExampleViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DatePickerViewController.h"
#import "DatePickerViewController2.h"

@interface DatePickerModalExampleViewController : UIViewController <DatePickerViewControllerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIButton *button;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button3; 

}






@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)buttonPressed2:(id)sender;
@end

DatePickerModalExampleViewController.m

#import "DatePickerModalExampleViewController.h"

@implementation DatePickerModalExampleViewController
@synthesize button;
@synthesize button2; 
@synthesize button3;


/*
 // The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
 // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
 - (void)loadView {
 }
 */


/*
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 }
 */

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"I was pressed");
    buttonPressed = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;

    DatePickerViewController *datePickerViewController = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DatePickerViewController" bundle:nil];
    datePickerViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:datePickerViewController animated:YES];
    [datePickerViewController release]; 



switch (((UIButton*)sender).tag) 
    {

        case 100001:
        NSLog(@"Button 1 was pressed");

            //some code
        break;
        case 100002:
        NSLog(@"Button 2 was pressed"); 

            //some code
        break;


    }
}   



-(IBAction)buttonPressed2:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"I was pressed2");
    buttonPressed2 = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;

    DatePickerViewController2 *datePickerViewController2 = [[DatePickerViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"DatePickerViewController2" bundle:nil];
    datePickerViewController2.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:datePickerViewController2 animated:YES];
    [datePickerViewController2 release];    



    switch (((UIButton*)sender).tag) 
    {


        case 100003:
            NSLog(@"Button 3 was pressed"); 

            //some code
            break;


    }
}   





-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.button.tag = 100001;
    self.button2.tag = 100002;
    self.button3.tag = 100003;
    buttonPressed = -1;
    buttonPressed2 = -1;


}


-(void)datePickerViewController:(DatePickerViewController *)controller didChooseDate:(NSString *)chosenDate{
    NSLog(@"Chosen Date as String: %@", chosenDate );

    if (buttonPressed == -1)
        return;  
    UIButton *buttonToSet = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:buttonPressed];
    buttonPressed = -1;  
    [buttonToSet setTitle: chosenDate forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}

-(void)datePickerViewController2:(DatePickerViewController2 *)controller didChooseDate:(NSString *)chosenDate{
    NSLog(@"Chosen Date as String: %@", chosenDate );

    if (buttonPressed2 == -1)
        return;  
    UIButton *buttonToSet = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:buttonPressed2];
    buttonPressed2 = -1;  
    [buttonToSet setTitle: chosenDate forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
}





/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [button3 release];
    [button2 release]; 
    [button release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Sorry i cant get you. could you post the question clearly?

Comment: I have 2 buttons, when I press one the date picker comes out, once I choose the date and I press done the date goes to both buttons instead than go only to the one that I pressed. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do not just dump code on here and expect us to know what you are talking about.  Ask a targeted question about some part of this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can set the property `"tag"` on button to identify it

Uncomment

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And type :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.button.tag = 100001;
self.button2.tag = 100002;

}
```

then
turn in **DatePickerModalExampleViewController.h**
`(IBAction)buttonPressed` **to** `(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;`

Then turn in **DatePickerModalExampleViewController.m**

`-(IBAction)buttonPressed` **to** `-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender`

and in **DatePickerModalExampleViewController.m** this method could be like that :

```
    -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
    {
        switch(((UIButton*)sender).tag)
        {
         case 100001   
               NSLog(@"Button 1 was pressed");
               DatePickerViewController *datePickerViewController =[DatePickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DatePickerViewController" bundle:nil];
               datePickerViewController.delegate = self;    
               [self presentModalViewController:datePickerViewController animated:YES];
               [datePickerViewController release]; 
            break;
         case 100002 : 
               NSLog(@"Button 2 was pressed");
               // some code
             break;
        }
    }
```

As you use the interfacebuilder I'm not friend with it but you must relink your actions
I'm writting from my PC so without xcode some code can contains syntax error be carreful. but it's the main idea.

Comment: Thank you very very much....I might not locating the switch in the right place.. it gives me an error. I located it under DatePickerModelExampleViewController under [self presentModalViewController:datePickerViewController animated:YES]; ...Where exactly do I need to locate it? Thank you so much! your help is very important to me!

Comment: I am sorry I am a very new programmer...what do you mean with set the property "tag" on the button?...you mean create connections in the .xib file?

Comment: The error is next to switch and says: expected identifier or '(' before 'switch'

Comment: sorry for the delay of my answer it's time difference (I'm in France)

Comment: Christophe, I think we are close. I have 3 errors:
next to viewDidLoad it says undeclared (first use in the function). The second error in the same line says: expected ";" before "{" token and the third says:Expected declaration or statement at end of imput

Comment: I am not sure what I can do. I tried to send you the code page but doesn't let me. the comments can have a very limited number of letters. I really appreciate your help...this piece of code as been a nightmare. Thank you!

Comment: Christophe, I just reedit my code in the same spot I posted before, so you can see the entire code

Comment: Christophe, I just fixed my errors, now I think I have to make the right connections to make it work....let's see!!! your help was very precious! Thank you!

Comment: yes, I solved it, it runs with no mistakes, but i still have the same problem. when I press the button and date piker comes out I chose the date and the date still goes to both buttons...I fixed the connections I believe, but I still have the same problem! It is driving me crazy!!!

Comment: the console gives me this : 2010-11-19 11:56:15.358 DatePickerModalExample[262:207] I was pressed
2010-11-19 11:56:15.368 DatePickerModalExample[262:207] Date Picker. viewDidLoad
2010-11-19 11:56:15.369 DatePickerModalExample[262:207] Button 1 was pressed
2010-11-19 11:56:17.143 DatePickerModalExample[262:207] Chosen Date as String: Nov 21, 2010
2010-11-19 11:56:17.145 DatePickerModalExample[262:207] Chosen Date2 as String: Nov 21, 2010 you see it choose contemporary chose Date and Chosen Date2...WHY??!!

Comment: I noticed I am asking far too many questions. Would you want to help me writing pieces of codes and I can pay for it. I really need a kind of tutor so I can learn quicker...what do you think? we could exchange our e-mails addresses. It might would be easier. What do you think?

Comment: DatePickerViewController *datePickerViewController = [[DatePickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DatePickerViewController" bundle:nil];
datePickerViewController.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:datePickerViewController animated:YES];
[datePickerViewController release];  must be in the case of the button you want

Comment: I 've just see my comment in the cases it's not //same code but //some code

Comment: I edited my answer... for the mail I prefer not even if I want help you stackoverflow have many people like me and my work take me a lot of time. Of course it's a pleasure if I could help you more.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!!! I am not very sure when you say "all that part of the code"  must be in the same case of the button you want?

Comment: just see the "switch" part of my answer, and compare of yours Good evening

Comment: Christophe, I wondering if you are able to give me some help with the following problem: I have 2 buttons with 2 different hours. I would like to be able to subtract them finding how many hours between one and other, subtract the result to a number that I digit in a third button and multiply that value by an other number that I digit in a fourth button and have the results in a 5th button. Do you have clue how to solve this problem? It would great if you can give me some suggestions. I really appreciate your help!Thank you!

Comment: @viviana hello viviana, can you open a new thread in stackoverflow for your question, I will see what can I do.

Comment: Good afternoon Christophe, thank you very much for your replay. I opened a new question and it is under the title:"operation between hours".....thank you so much!

Comment: Christophe, they took me out stackoverflow....wooo I didn't aspect that...I really appreciated your help! thank you!

Comment: Hi Christopher, sorry I didn't see your message, merry christmas and happy new year to you too!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use tag for both buttons and check the condition accordingly...

Comment: @viviana: Your tag needs to be a number.